# Error when importing Tensorflow in my project

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, six

My project is in Python 3.7, anaconda Jupyter Notebook on windows 10.
When I try to import Tensorflow i get the following error message:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Guilherme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\Guilherme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio
  File "C:\Users\Guilherme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\audio\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "C:\Users\Guilherme\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_audio_ops.py", line 7, in <module>
    import six as _six
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
>>>
```

I have tried to install this 'six', but it says "Requeriments already satisfied"

What should I do?

Comment: The error shows TF being loaded from a non-Anaconda Python location. Ensure that `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` do not contain paths leading to that Python interpreter nor its packages. Also, make sure that you are running the Anaconda Python (e.g., `import sys; print(sys.executable)`) as your kernel.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how do i do this Path thing?